# Array Index pattern issue while using *ngIf inside ngFor In Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

```
data=[
      {name:"Danger",color:"red",intensity:100},
      {name:"Success",color:"green",intensity:20},
      {name:"Warning",color:"yellow",intensity:70},
      {name:"cool",color:"blue",intensity:80}

     ]

<div *ngFor="let element of data;let i=index">
   <span *ngIf="element.intensity>50">
    {{i+1}} {{element.name}}
   </span>
</div>
```

```
Output:
1.Danger
3.Warning
4.cool
```

```
Desired Output
1.Danger
2.Warning
3.cool
```

In the index 2 is missing because no element was displayed at index 2
but i want output as my desired output.

Any suggestion or help is most appreciated.

Comment: Can't you filter the date before rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - Filter in @Component**:

`@Component`:

```
this.filteredData = this.data.filter(({ intensity }) => intensity > 50);
```

`HTML`:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of filteredData; index as i">
  {{ i + 1 }} {{ element.name }}
</div>
```

**Option 2 - Filter in @Pipe**:

`@Pipe`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByIntensity'
})
export class FilterByIntensityPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[]): any[] { // Put the correspondent interface here
    return value.filter(({ intensity }) => intensity > 50);
  }
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of data | filterByIntensity; index as i">
  {{ i + 1 }} {{ element.name }}
</div>
```

Note that this a very specific `@Pipe`. I'd recommend you to create something more generic, like `filterBy` where you can pass the properties to be filtered, etc. and why not even reuse it elsewhere.